# Hide/Show Parent Widget using child Swich widget

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have a parent widget in which multiple child widgets are in a CustomScrollView. I want to show / hide CustomScrollView widgets via a child switch widget. My widget structure like this:

```
CustomScrollView(
        controller: controller,
        slivers: <Widget>[

          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: new TabPanel()),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: new UrlButtonPanel()),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: new ChatNowAd()),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: new LatestNewsController(),), //---> my switch widget is here
          newsListSliver //--> want to controll this view via switch,

          !canLoad ? SliverToBoxAdapter(child: new Center(child: lazyLoading,))  : SliverToBoxAdapter(child: new Container())
        ],
      );
```

If someone activates the `LatestNewsController ()` option then `newsListSliver` will be visible again if the turnoff then`newsListSliver` will be invisible.

**How to access my Switch widget so you can control other CustomScrollView widgets?**

Comment: Where do you have that switch to toggle NewsController

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian LatestNewsController() in this widget. check out my code comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Visibility Widget to manage the Visibility of your widgets.

```
Visibility(
 child: Your_Widget,
 visible: true/false,
),
```

`true` means visible and `false` means invisible.